# Best method of NLOS video transfer to 2km distance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wimax

I'm trying to transfer HD video at 4000kbps(4Mbits) from a mobile device (motorbike) to a stationary device (main computer) having a maximum distance between them of 2km.

I've found that WiMAX have good NLOS bandwith under 5km distance, but all the bussiness that make WiMAX installations that I ask say that is really difficult to achieve this, but the more that I read, the more that I see that WiMAX is perfect for this.

Also, I've read that there are some 4g emitters and receivers (GSM? Don't really know what I'm talking about...), and knowing that mobile phones have good bandwith around an entire city maybe I can create my own 4g link to my computer and my motorbike.

The thing is, Seems that there are some solutions for this, but I don't know where to start to check something that could work. For exampl,e, how I create my own WiMAX network? I don't know what I have to buy, and I have read that WiMAX have tons of technologies or whatever they are to optimize each situation (Ghz? OFDM?...), and I don't know what is the best for a mobile device under 2km NLOS.

Also, I'll appreciate if someone knows another system to achieve this that I haven't found.

Comment: If you have 4G coverage, why not just stream direct to a streaming service rather than a computer?

Comment: @Paul Because not always I'm going to have 4G coverage because each weekend the system will be mounted in a different town. We want to stream the town 'running' events to the public waiting in the finish line, and in my country there is not much 4G coverage by the companies (60% I think right now), and some times the runners will go up and down a mountain without mobile coverage and those things. Btw, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It might be worth editing out the part where you say "mobile phones have good bandwith around the entire city"

Comment: @Paul No no, I meant, "an entire city", saying that GSM (3g, 4g, whatever) looks like a powerful long range wireless communication system too.